# can we use selenium when such a table is not having proper html like shown below?

Tags: selenium

Here is the table that I am using to get the table row element that has specific element such as the href that has 'Harvest' in text and also checking if text 'running' exists in the same table row.

```
<table id="execTable" class="tableHistory jobtable translucent">
   <colgroup>
      <col class="execid">
      <col class="titlecol">
   </colgroup>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th>Id</th>
         <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tr id="8571">
      <td>8571</td>
      <td class="titlecol">
         <div id="hitdiv-8571" class="arrow"></div>
         <a href="/job?id=Harvest&amp;logs">Harvest</a>
      </td>
      <td>09-03-2015 09:45:04</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>2m 6s</td>
      <td>running</td>
      <td><a href="flow?action=restart&amp;id=8571">view/restart</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="8571-child" class="childRow" style="display: none;"></tr>
   <tr id="8566">
      <td>8566</td>
      <td class="titlecol">
         <div id="hitdiv-8566" class="arrow"></div>
         <a href="/job?id=mk trained input&amp;logs">mk</a>
      </td>
      <td>09-03-2015 03:30:00</td>
      <td>09-03-2015 04:16:50</td>
      <td>46m 50s</td>
      <td>succeeded</td>
      <td><a href="/flow?action=restart&amp;id=8566">view/restart</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="8555-child" class="childRow" style="display: none;"></tr>
</table>
```

I am not able to get the `TR`s.

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("execTable"));
List<WebElement> trows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
```

Comment: What happens when you try to run the code? Please edit your question to include what your results are and what you have tried, if anything, in addition to what you posted here so far. P.S. You may be able to find the element using a different locator, or by selecting all tr's and filtering through them (though possibly not the most efficient method).

Comment: I ended up using the code below as      `List<WebElement> all = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='execTable']/*"));
            for (WebElement a : all) {  ...}`

Comment: When you post blocks of code, go ahead and put 4 spaces at the front of each line instead of using the grave marker. The grave markers are for code in a sentence. It makes it easier to read.

Comment: What happens when you run that code? You aren't getting the `TR`s that are outside of `TBODY`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<WebElement> all = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='execTable']/*"));

for (WebElement a : all) {

                if(a.getTagName().equalsIgnoreCase("tr")) { ....}
}
```

I was able to get the above code working. Thank you!